# Is there a mistake in the C standard description of pointer declarators?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

C 2018 6.7.6.1 1 says:

> If, in the declaration “**T D1**”, **D1** has the form
>
> ***** *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> **D**
>
> and the type specified for *ident* in the declaration “**T D**” is
> “*derived-declarator-type-list* *T*”, then the type specified for *ident*
> is “*derived-declarator-type-list* *type-qualifier-list* pointer to *T*”.
> For each type qualifier in the list, *ident* is a so-qualified pointer.

This question is about the final sentence, but let’s work through the first one first.

Consider the declaration `int * const * foo`. Here **T** is `int`, **D1** is `* const * foo`, *type-qualifier-list* is `const`, and **D** is `* foo`.

Then **T D** is `int * foo`, and that specifies “pointer to `int`” for the *ident* `foo`, so *derived-declarator-type-list* is “pointer to”. (There is no overt explanation of *derived-declarator-type-list* in the standard, but 6.7.8 3, discussing `typedef`, says it “is specified by the declarators of **D**.”)

Substituting these into the final clause of the first sentence tells us that **T D1** specifies the type for `foo` is “pointer to `const` pointer to `int`”. Fine so far.

But then the final sentence tells us that for each type qualifier in the list (which is `const`), *ident* is a so-qualified pointer. So it says `foo` is a `const` pointer.

But it is not; we commonly interpret `int * const * foo` to declare `foo` to be a non-`const` pointer to a `const` pointer to `int`.

Is this a mistake in the standard or is there another interpretation for the final sentence?

Comment: I guess that T is changing the meaning within the paragraph. Once it is `int`, next it refers to `int *const`.

Comment: I guess you are saying the standard did not make it explicit how to recursively apply the grammar for multiple `*`s.

Comment: @tstanisl: **T** cannot be `int * const`. It comes from the *declaration-specifiers* part of the declaration, which can have only storage class specifiers, type specifiers, type qualifiers, function specifiers (`inline` and `_Noreturn`), and alignment specifiers. The pointer token, `*`, is not a part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, there are three answers that were deleted by their authors, supporting a conclusion that this aspect of the C standard is tricky. I do not believe the other current answer correctly matches the example source text (`int * const * foo`) to the symbols in the passage from the standard (**T**, **D1**, *type-qualifier-list*, and so on).

Thus I conclude this is indeed a mistake in the standard.

I believe a fix is simply to remove the last sentence, “For each type qualifier in the list, *ident* is a so-qualified pointer.” Any qualifier in the *type-qualifier* list is already incorporated, correctly, into the previous sentence, and any qualifier inside *D* is already incorporated in that declarator. So this seems like just a superfluous sentence that may have arisen inadvertently in some edit.

Answer (score 2):

With **T** as `int` and **D** as `* foo`, the "T D" does not give *ident* the type **T**, but **pointer to T**.

The second part of the `if`:

> If ... **and** the type specified for ident in the declaration “T D” is
> “derived-declarator-type-list T”

seems to make sure that the *nesting* is correct.

With two stars, you would have to use D2 - D1 - D before you reach the direct declarator.

The second example:

```
typedef int *int_ptr;
const int_ptr foo;
```

shows how tricky it can get; `const` is far away from *ident*, but still the pointer is constant, not the data.

The specs call this a clarification - now *that* is a mistake.

---

Interestingly in the next section "6.7.6.2 Array declarators" there is a *footnote* after the corresponding semantical definition:

> When several "array of" specifications are adjacent, a
> multidimensional array is declared.

The case of several adjacent "pointer of" specifications is not mentioned. Kind of a "mistake".

---

In 1988 the "Reference Manual" had the D1 and D switched (!), but otherwise  the wording is almost identical. (there is *type-modifier* instead of *derived-declarator-type-list*).

The examples are similar: the main example is `int *ap[]`:

> Here ap[] plays the role of D1; a declaration "int ap[]" would ...

With `int **pp`, `*pp` plays that role.

Comment: Note that I fixed an error in the question. “Then **T D** is `int * foo`, and that specifies “pointer to `int`” for **D**, so *derived-declarator-type-list* is “pointer to”’ has been changed to “Then **T D** is `int * foo`, and that specifies “pointer to `int`” for the *ident* `foo`, so *derived-declarator-type-list* is “pointer to”.” Regarding your first sentence, yes **T D** gives *ident*, which is `foo`, the type “pointer to **T**“. Then we have `T` is `int`, *derived-declarator-type-list* is “pointer to”, and *type-qualifier-list* is `const`…

Comment: … Substituting these into “… the type specified for *ident* is “*derived-declarator-type-list* *type-qualifier-list* pointer to T” gives “the type specified for `foo` is “pointer to const pointer to `int`”. Still fine. But the final quoted sentence is still a problem. *type-qualifier-list* is `const`, and the final sentence says “For each type qualifier in the list, *ident* is a so-qualified pointer.” So that says `foo` is a `const`-qualified pointer. But it is not.